# How to draw date in x-axis in Area Chart?

Tags: charts, google-apps-script, google-visualization

I have the following data in a Google Spreadsheet:

```
ColumnA     ColumnB
Departament Quantity
01/01/2016  23
02/01/2016  43
04/01/2016  5
06/01/2016  65
10/01/2016  12
11/01/2016  32
13/01/2016  22
15/02/2016  2
```

And want to draw a linechart using HTML Templates: This is my code so far now

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="main"></div>
<script>
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(getSpreadsheetData);

function getSpreadsheetData() {
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(drawChart).getSpreadsheetData();   
}

function drawChart(rows) {
  var options = {'title':'Example','width':400,'height':300};
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rows, false);     
  var chart = newgoogle.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("main"));
  chart.draw(data, options)
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My script to read the sheet:

```
function getSpreadsheetData() { 
var ssID   = "12GvIStMKqmRFNBM-C67NCDeb89-c55K7KQtcuEYmJWQ",
    sheet  = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheets()[0],
    data   = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();  
return data;    
}
```

However i cant draw the plot, this issue dissapear when i change the data to a numeric (i.e. 42370), but thats not what i want!

[image: x axis does not show date in format "dd/mm/yyyy"]

Question is: what do i have to add in order to change to the right format in x axis?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `hAxis.format` [configuration option](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options)

`var options = {'title':'Example','width':400,'height':300,//-->'format':'MM/dd/yyyy'};`

The valid format options can be found [here](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classSimpleDateFormat.html#_details)...

And if you need to load with a specific locale, see [this](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#loadwithlocale)...

Comment: Thanks for your answer unfortunatelly the charts remain the same, it seems the code just ignores the haxis.format statement (obviously the comment part was removed)

Comment: do you know if it is loading as a string or an actual date? you could check with [`data.getColumnType(0)`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_getColumnType)

Comment: It seems the problem is the function arrayToDataTable that only works with numbers and doesnt take date formats with an spreadsheet. I think it is a bug and made a report, hope to find a solution soon :)